# C# Checking if button was clicked

Tags: c#, button, click

I am making a program that should just continue if 2 conditions are given.

The first one, 2 `TextBox`s have the same word in and a `Button` was clicked, which opens a new `Form`. Now I have the event for the "complete" button.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox2.Text == textBox3.Text && ???) 
    {    
        StreamWriter myWriter = File.CreateText(@"c:\Program Files\text.txt");
        myWriter.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);
        myWriter.WriteLine(textBox2.Text);
     }
]
```

My problem is, I can't find a method that gives something like `button1.Clicked or something similar.

I hope someone can help me here..

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`Click` is an event that fires immediately after you release the mouse button. So if you want to check in the handler for `button2.Click` if `button1` was clicked before, all you could do is have a handler for `button1.Click` which sets a bool flag of your own making to true.

```
private bool button1WasClicked = false;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1WasClicked = true;
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox2.Text == textBox3.Text && button1WasClicked)
    { 
        StreamWriter myWriter = File.CreateText(@"c:\Program Files\text.txt");
        myWriter.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);
        myWriter.WriteLine(textBox2.Text);
        button1WasClicked = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to reset the flag after you check it.  Otherwise, it will only work once.

Comment: Where do i have to fill in private bool button1WasClicked = false; ?

Comment: Its a field inside your form class.

Comment: What can i do if my system says that the acces was denied for creating the text file?

Comment: Not store your text file under Program Files. That folder is specially protected in modern Windows versions :)

Comment: is this method applied if I have multiples Buttons??

Comment: @user3821206 Sure, why not. Have one boolean flag for each button.

Answer (score 0):

These helped me a lot: I wanted to save values from my gridview, and it was reloading my gridview /overriding my new values, as i have IsPostBack inside my PageLoad.

```cs
if (HttpContext.Current.Request["MYCLICKEDBUTTONID"] == null)
{
   //Do not reload the gridview.

}
else
{
   reload my gridview.
}
```

SOURCE: http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/312809-please-help-how-identify-button-clicked

Answer (score 0):

button1, button2 and button3 have same even handler

```
private void button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btnSender = (Button)sender;
        if (btnSender == button1 || btnSender == button2)
        {
            //some code here
        }
        else if (btnSender == button3)
            //some code here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i am very new to this website. I am an undergraduate student, doing my Bachelor Of Computer Application.
I am doing a simple program in Visual Studio using C# and I came across the same problem, how to check whether a button is clicked?
I wanted to do this,

```
if(-button1 is clicked-) then
{
this should happen;
}
if(-button2 is clicked-) then
{
this should happen;
}
```

I didn't know what to do, so I tried searching for the solution in the internet. I got many solutions which didn't help me. So, I tried something on my own and did this,

```
int i;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            i = 1;
            label3.Text = "Principle";
            label4.Text = "Rate";
            label5.Text = "Time";
            label6.Text = "Simple Interest";
        }


private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            i = 2;
            label3.Text = "SI";
            label4.Text = "Rate";
            label5.Text = "Time";
            label6.Text = "Principle";
        }
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
                if (i == 1)
                {
                    si = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) * Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text) * Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text)) / 100;
                    textBox4.Text = Convert.ToString(si);
                }
                if (i == 2)
                {
                    p = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) * 100) / (Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text) * Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text));
                    textBox4.Text = Convert.ToString(p);
                }
```

I declared a variable "i" and assigned it with different values in different buttons and checked the value of i in the if function. 
It worked. Give your suggestions if any. Thank you.