# How to use check a Button in another Button statement? c#

Tags: c#

I am having a problem . I want to use if statement to check if a button is clicked. For Example:

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    while (1)
    {
         ...
         ...
         ...

         if (Button2 == clicked)
         {
              break;
         }
    }
}
```

But it's not working like this, because the ".click" can only be on the left side of "+=" or "-=". Any idea how i can check if Button2 is clicked?

the code is loking like this: and i want to check button2 to stop the "programm".
the check for the Button2 is nearly at the end of the code ;)

```
    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int EmFilterPos;
        int ExFilterPos;
        string String1;
        int[] EmLB = new int[126];
        int[] ExLB = new int[126];
        int LBEmAnzahl = 0;
        int LBEmTot = 0;
        int LBExAnzahl = 0;
        int LBExTot = 0;

        UInt32 C_Zyklen;
        UInt32 Zyklen;

        Roche.DetectionControl2.Device_Filterwheels.ELBPowerState LB_On = Roche.DetectionControl2.Device_Filterwheels.ELBPowerState.LBOn;
        Roche.DetectionControl2.Device_Filterwheels.ELBPowerState LB_Off = Roche.DetectionControl2.Device_Filterwheels.ELBPowerState.LBOff;
        Roche.DetectionControl2.Device_Filterwheels.fiweGetLBResponse LightBarrier;

        string Text = String.Format("Filterrad-Dauertest\r\nGestart am {0:d} um {0:t}\r\n\r\n", DateTime.Now);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"TestLogFile\Filterrad_Dauertest1.txt", Text);

        Instrument.N1_DetectionControl2_1_Device_Filterwheels.fiweInitFilter();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);

        while (Zyklen <= 20)
        {
            for (int q=1;q<8;q++)
            {
                Instrument.N1_DetectionControl2_1_Device_Filterwheels.fiweMove(q,q);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
                Zyklen++;


            }

            for (int w=0;w<7;w++)
            {
                ExFilterPos = rnd.Next(1,8);
                EmFilterPos = rnd.Next(1,8);
                Instrument.N1_DetectionControl2_1_Device_Filterwheels.fiweMove(ExFilterPos,EmFilterPos);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
                Zyklen++;
            }

            C_Zyklen = Zyklen;
            if ((C_Zyklen % 2) < 14)
            {
                Instrument.N1_DetectionControl2_1_Device_Filterwheels.fiweInitFilter();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
                using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter (@"TestLogFile\Filterrad_Dauertest1.txt", true))
                {
                    file.Write("Init bei: ");
                    String1 = String.Format("{0,7}",Zyklen);
                    file.Write(String1);
                    file.Write(file.NewLine);
                }

                ExFilterPos = 60;
                EmFilterPos = 60;
                Instrument.N1_DetectionControl2_1_Device_Filterwheels.fiweRawMove(ExFilterPos,EmFilterPos);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
                Instrument.N1_DetectionControl2_1_Device_Filterwheels.fiweSetLB(LB_On);

                while (EmFilterPos != -60)
                {
                    LightBarrier = Instrument.N1_DetectionControl2_1_Device_Filterwheels.fiweGetLB();
                    if (LightBarrier.LBEm == Roche.DetectionControl2.Device_Filterwheels.ELBState.LBbright)
                    {
                        LBEmAnzahl++;
                        LBEmTot += EmFilterPos;
                    }
                    if (LightBarrier.LBEx == Roche.DetectionControl2.Device_Filterwheels.ELBState.LBbright)
                    {
                        LBExAnzahl++;
                        LBExTot += ExFilterPos;
                    }
                    ExFilterPos--;
                    EmFilterPos--;
                    Instrument.N1_DetectionControl2_1_Device_Filterwheels.fiweRawMove(ExFilterPos,EmFilterPos);
                }
                EmFilterPos = LBEmTot / LBEmAnzahl;
                ExFilterPos = LBExTot / LBExAnzahl;

                using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter (@"TestLogFile\Filterrad_Dauertest1.txt", true))
                {
                    file.Write("Nullstelle Mittelposition Em-Filter: ");
                    file.Write(EmFilterPos);
                    file.Write(file.NewLine);
                    file.Write("Nullstelle Mittelposition Ex-Filter: ");
                    file.Write(ExFilterPos);
                    file.Write(file.NewLine);
                    file.Write(file.NewLine);
                }

                Instrument.N1_DetectionControl2_1_Device_Filterwheels.fiweSetLB(LB_Off);
            }

            if (Button2 == clicked)   // or something like this
                 break;
        }

        using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter (@"TestLogFile\Filterrad_Dauertest1.txt", true))
        {
            file.Write("Beendet am {0:d} um {0:t}\r\n", DateTime.Now);
        }*/
    }
```

Comment: Button2 *wasn't* clicked.  *Button1* was clicked.  Because you're in the click handler for Button1.  Or is this same handler being used for both buttons?  (In which case it should probably be re-named.)  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553768/c-sharp-checking-if-button-was-clicked

Comment: @AlekDepler: And your *guess* may coincidentally be correct.  But the OP should still clarify in the question.

Comment: You get that error because .Click is an event, not a property, you already got the answer, one of the options you have is using a flag.

Comment: no the thing with the flag is not working, because if the programm is in the Button1 statement, it will not leave it until it has finished the hole process, so if i press Button1 to start the programm it will finisch it and only now i'm able to set the button2 flag to true

Comment: Then use a separated Thread and do..while flag == false.
Or if you are using wpf use ICommand.CanExecute

Comment: @RBuri: What you're describing doesn't make any sense to me.  All of this logic is happening in response to clicking Button1.  So *Button1* was clicked.  *Not Button2*.  If you want to do something when *Button2* is clicked, you'd do it in *that button's* click handler function.  Just like you're already putting logic in this click handler function for Button1.

Comment: @RBuri: It sounds like your Button1 should be starting a background thread.  And Button2 should signal that thread.

Comment: Inherit from class Button and create your weird behaviour. But it would be the same as the flag, kind of.
Threads is another option.
Async is another option.

Comment: @TareqB. can you give me an example how to make a separated thread?

Comment: @RBuri I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beside the weird behavior you want..and since you are not using Threads, you have the following options:

Local functions (.Net > 4.7)

```
private void B_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool clickFlag = false;
    void Click(object sender2, EventArgs e2)
    {
        clickFlag = true;
    }

    b2.Click += Click;

    while (!clickFlag)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1);
    }

    b2.Click -= Click;


    //Continue with your stuff
}
```

Threads

```
Thread newThread;
private void Button1_Click()
{
    newThread = new Thread(YourBreakableProcess);
    newThread.Start();
}
private void Button2_Click()
{
    newThread.Join();
}
private void YourBreakableProcess()
{
    //Your breakable process
}
```

Async methods.

I hope you find a solution. Cheers.

Edit: 
Since what you want is to interrupt the process of whatever you are doing, the only option you have is Local fuctions as shown above, if you are not tied to a specific framework version.

BackgroundWorker and check in every step if the button 2 was pressed with the flag thing mentioned in other answer.

Threads, and make a thread.Join when the button 2 is pressed.

Edit 2: 
Updated answer with Threads, I will recommend that if you go with this option it is much better to use a BackgroundWorker instead as you will have the whole control of the process breaking it only in the place where it would be fine to break it.

Comment: it's working how it hast to, i made it with threads, thanks alot @TareqB.

Comment: Glad to hear that, but I will really recommend you to use backgroundworker instead, it would be easy to implement, and without any bad behavior because you can choose when to break the loop just checking a property of the worker just before any step in your process. Join will destruct the thread in any step, imagine that you do the join in the middle of the file creation for example.

Answer (score 1):

Hm...

```
bool b1clicked = false, b2clicked = false;
public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   b2clicked = true;
}

public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   b1clicked = true;
   if (b1clicked && b2clicked)
   {
      //...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using a `flag` variable. Declare and initialize `flag` value to `false`.On `button2` click change flag value to `true` as follows,

```
private bool flag= false;

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    flag= true;
}

public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Use flag to check whether button 2 has clicked or not
    if (flag)
    {

    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```