# C# checking what button was pressed

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I know about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553768/c-sharp-checking-if-button-was-clicked) but it does not addres my issue.

Suppose we have two buttons that do the very same thing (load csv file and feed the data in two variables) but on two different sets of variables. I can write two functions dedicated to both functions, but they will share too much common code.

How can I detect what button called the callback function to decide what set of variables to work on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the `Button` by casting the `sender` argument.

You should use an explicit cast instead of (the often seen) `as` operator, because it would correctly result in an `InvalidCastException` when the sender is unexpectedly not a Button.

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var button = (Button)sender;
    // Use button properties to differentiate and load to your variables accordingly
}
```